# Magento 2. config.xml and how to use it

Tags: magento2, configuration

What is the purpose of `config.xml` file in M2.

- How to use it (examples).
- How does one config file interact with other config files from other modules
- Is it mandatory to put our nodes under the default node?

Answer (score 7):

The `config.xml` file is used to set default values for system configuration (in Admin under Stores > Settings > Configuration), set in `<module_folder>/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`.

All the `config.xml` files will be merged together into one tree. If you overwrite another module's config, it will depend on load order (you would need to specify the other module as a dependency).

Also keep in mind that once you change system config values in the admin and save them, then the values in `config.xml` will no longer apply; they will be overwritten in the `core_config_data` table. They are meant only to specify defaults.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the purpose of config.xml file in M2.

Its used to add default system configuration values.

> How to use it (examples).

Use it when you need system configuration to have default values. Best way to know how to use it is to see how core uses them, there is tons of examples in the core code.

> How does one config file interact with other config files from other
>   modules. Is it mandatory to put our nodes under the default node?

It uses XPATH's of other XML files to give default values. No you don't need to put everything under the `default` node. If you have a look at `Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd` you'll see you have the option to use `default`, `stores` and `websites` as the main node (after config).

I would suggest to generate the xsd configuration for your xml files, this way if you use a smart IDE it will help you auto complete XML files and know what nodes you are able to use. Magento has a built in command.

```
bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate
```

If you use Phpstorm then do this

```
bin/magento  dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

1. it's used to added default values to system configuration , which
   already set
2. in my example in screenshot i used to target shipping method in
   default domain . u can use  `[default - stores - websites ] domain` 
   -> which set in `Magento_Store` Module in `etc/config.xsd`
3. 3.it can be override by provid another config in separated module which will set as dependence in your `Module.xml`.
4. when you change it from admin it will be override by can be restored .
5. [image: List item]